# Replace corresponding white pixels from one image with RGB pixels from another image

Tags: python

I have 2 images - one of the images is binarized i.e. each pixel is either black or white, and the other image is a standard RGB image. Both images are of the same size. For all the white pixels in the first image, I would like to take the corresponding pixels in the RGB image and attach them in place of the white pixels. How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the binarized image as a binary index for the pixel coordinates:

```py
import numpy as np

my_source_image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (480,640,3), np.uint8) # defined somewhere, assumed to have shape [H,W,3]
my_binarized_image = np.random.randint(0, 2, (480,640), np.uint8) # defined somewhere, assumed to have shape [H,W]
pixel_idx = my_binarized_image.astype(bool)
my_dest_image = np.zeros_like(my_source_image)
my_dest_image[pixel_idx,:] = my_source_image[pixel_idx]
```

Note that I define the destination image as all-zeroes (if you want a different background color, simply initialize to the color value instead) and then fill in the relevant pixels instead of reusing `my_binarized_image` as you see to require in your question, because the destination image needs three channels, while the binarized image only has one.

Alternatively, as long as the "background" color is black, you can avoid preallocating a second image and simply zero-out the pixels in the first image instead:

```
my_dest_image = my_source_image * pixel_idx[...,None]
```

(The `[...,None]` adds an extra dimension at the end of `pixel_idx` to make the pixel-wise multiplication possible)

Comment: I get a `IndexError: too many indices for array` error when I try this